# Ajax wont prepend div

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I have a basic comment section where people can submit feedback and reply to other people's feedback. I have made the feedback submission with ajax and it works properly, the div is being prepended to the parent element without the need of refresh. However, when I try to prepend the reply to feedback, it does not update the content, only once I refresh, the reply is added.
Reply jquery

```
$(function () {
    const $replyForm = $('#send-reply-form');

    $replyForm.on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const dataToSend = $replyForm.serialize();

        $.post($replyForm.attr('action'), dataToSend, function (serverData) {
            $('.comments-list').prepend(serverData);
        })
    })
})
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddReply(AddFeedbackViewModel model)
        {
            var feedbackModel = await this.feedbackService.AddReply(model);

            return this.PartialView("_ReplySectionPartial", feedbackModel);
        }
```

_ReplySectionPartial

```
@model FeedbackViewModel

<div class="single-comment replyComment justify-content-between d-flex">
    <div class="user justify-content-between d-flex">
        <div class="thumb">
            <img src="~/images/blog/c6.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
            <h5>
                <a href="#">@Model.Name</a>
            </h5>
            <p class="date">@Model.CreatedOn.Value.ToLongDateString()</p>
            <p class="comment">
                @Model.Comment
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What could the problem be, why would it not update until it has been refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around, added id to the parent element and used it to prepend to it.

```
$(function () {
    const $replyForm = $('#send-reply-form');

    $replyForm.on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const dataToSend = $replyForm.serialize();

        const dataArray = $replyForm.serializeArray();
        var feedbackId = dataArray[0].value;

        const feedbackParentElement = $('#' + feedbackId);

        $.post($replyForm.attr('action'), dataToSend, function (serverData) {
            $(feedbackParentElement).prepend(serverData);
        })
    })
})
```